# Cloudflare issued SSL to reverse proxy fullchain error(through docker)

Tags: wordpress, nginx, ssl, cloudflare, nginx-reverse-proxy

background: have a nginx server running a separate GUI/domain, so using docker to setup a wordpress site for a different domain and different port number.
got that all working(with IP:PORT) and now trying to link the domain to the IP/PORT(whilst still running through cloudflare).

firstly, my wordpress.conf file:

````
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/certificate.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/sslkey.key;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
  client_max_body_size 40M;
  server_tokens off;
  root /srv/;
 

  location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass         https://example.com:8845/80;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
  }



  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }


  location /fancyindex {


  }

 
  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript;
  

}```

now, i get the error:
```nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate "/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem"
nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/certificate.pem"
````

my key & certificate are both issued from origin server on cloudflare.
it did not come with a fullchain(and no idea how to get a fullchain - but if anyone knows how, that'd be helpful).
now my website wont link without it working.
ive wasted about 8 days working this out so need some sort of guidance to get this thing working.

Comment: got fullchain working on letsencrypt, but reverse proxy still wont work

Comment: What's the error you're seeing when you access through Cloudflare (domain)?